# Capturing the idea of "almost/nearly" and "actually"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's take **failing a test** as an example.

I would like to capture the class of people consisting of those who actually failed the test and who nearly failed the test.

Is there an elegant way of saying this? I would like to apply this to other situations as well.

Thanks for any hints in this matter.

Comment: You described it in your second sentence, so I'm not sure how else you'd like it to be said. What do you mean by other properties?

Comment: HI Jason: 1/ I would like to say this more succinctly. It is clunky right now. 2/ Other properties could be: being drunk, being in love, etc etc. I would like to capture elegantly having the property or nearly having the property.

Comment: The **Borderline** case.

Comment: @kris That's good but would only apply to those who only just passed and those who only just failed. It would not apply to those who failed dismally. I wonder if the OP wants to include the definite fails, if not then you have the answer.

Comment: You say you are giving the 'test passing' scenario as an example. Are you literally looking for a phrase to describe that instance or are you trying to find some sort of formula which will also be applicable in other situations? For what it's worth, I would define them by that which they have in common even though that is a negative attribute,, which is that they are those who 'did not achieve a passing grade of over [whatever you deen to be more than 'almost failing']'.

Comment: I would like to apply it in other circumstances (in math, actually). I could go "negative" but I am looking for something positive maybe it does not exist.

Comment: @BoldBen True, which is why it's a comment, not an answer! Just trying to zero-in on.

Comment: @Kris Me too also, I hope the OP clarifies what he means.

Comment: @BoldBen I would like to capture *all* failures (barely or miserably) and those who *nearly but actually didn't* fail the test. I don't want to say *those who didn't clearly pass the test*, i.e., I don't want to go "negative". I come to the conclusion that what I want does not exist, based on the answers and comments. Thanks!

Comment: Depending how "not negative" you can go, how could your set be other than "those who achieved less than (whatever mark mattered)"?

Comment: I don't think there is a universal idiom that suits all the scenarios/examples you state. What's wrong with "almost"?

Comment: Aren't you talking about someone whose grade fell below, say, 75 on the test?

Answer (score -2):

Two potential elegant adverbs are,

**virtually** [M-A](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtually)

> *Meaning*: nearly; almost.
>
> *Usage*:
> "the disease destroyed virtually all the vineyards in Orange County"

**well nigh** [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-nigh)

> *Meaning*: nearly; almost.
>
> *Usage*: "a task that is well-nigh impossible."

Comment: Thanks for these two words. Unfortunately, they both imply "not quite" which is not what I want. I want something that is nearly and actually, in one elegant word.

Comment: You can use **verge**, **precipice**. If you like I can add it in the answer.

Comment: I think it has the same problem, unfortunately. Thanks though, ubi!

Comment: @max_zorn tightly, closely